# Php service set up error

Tags: php, mysql, apache-flex, wampserver

while I try to connect to php service in flex I got an error like this.(I gave root,password,database name everything correctly)

```
Warning: mysqli_connect() [<a href='function.mysqli-connect'>function.mysqli-connect</a>]: MySQL server has gone away in C:\wamp\www\harisample\services\SamplePhp.php on line 54
```

Comment: Where do you get the error?  In Flex?  Or from he server?

Answer (score 0):

When you receive a `MySQL server has gone away` error, it means that one of the following is happening:

1. The client couldn't send a question to the server.
2. The client didn't get an error when writing to the server, but it
   didn't get a full answer (or any answer) to the question.
3. You tried to run a query after closing the connection to the server. This indicates a logic error in the application that should be corrected.
4. A client application running on a different host does not have the necessary privileges to connect to the MySQL server from that host.
5. The MYSQL_OPT_READ_TIMEOUT or MYSQL_OPT_WRITE_TIMEOUT variables are too low
6. You have encountered a timeout on the server side and the automatic reconnection in the client is disabled (the reconnect flag in the MYSQL structure is equal to 0).
7. You are using a Windows client and the server had dropped the connection (probably because wait_timeout expired) before the command was issued.

Fixing this can be simple, but only if you have full root access to your server.

1. You can change the time limit by setting the wait_timeout variable when you start mysqld. See [this link for more information](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html).
2. If you have a script, you just have to issue the query again for the client to do an automatic reconnection. This assumes that you have automatic reconnection in the client enabled (which is the default for the mysql command-line client).